# My new 116TB external SSD works in Windows, but not Ubuntu

Tags: usb, ssd

I have a new [cheap, chinese] external SSD, 16TB. This comes up as an exFAT drive of correct capacity, and takes data on my work Windows PC, but produces a litany of errors in Ubuntu & isn't recognised.

1. Is there an upper limit at work here?
2. Does anyone know a fix please?

The litany (dmesg) shows it recognising it to be a Very Large Capacity Drive, trying a few things, several of them twice, & then giving up. The desktop shows no reaction at all when I plug it in.

I don't suppose it helps but it's a "portable SSD" & says "MOBLLE SDUD STATE" on the case - which is, I suppose, a warning of sorts. I'm not wanting to do anything clever like boot from it, just use it for files.
So, details:

```
[   14.239812] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[   14.239812] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[   35.592132] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   35.741026] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=048d, idProduct=1234, bcdDevice= 1.00
[   35.741029] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   35.741030] usb 3-3: Product: Product
[   35.741031] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Vendor
[   35.741033] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: A1
[   35.762623] usb-storage 3-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   35.762821] scsi host0: usb-storage 3-3:1.0
[   35.762968] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   35.765626] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   36.772793] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SDK      ssd              5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   36.773257] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   36.773663] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[   36.773833] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096000000 4096-byte logical blocks: (16.8 TB/15.3 TiB)
[   36.773943] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   36.773945] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[   36.774071] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[   36.774076] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   36.800741] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[   36.804325] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   36.804328] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[   36.804331] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[   36.804333] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 f4 23 ff ff 00 00 01 00
[   36.804337] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 32767999992 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   36.804342] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 4095999999, async page read
[   36.804349] Alternate GPT is invalid, using primary GPT.
[   36.804359]  sda: sda1 sda2
[   36.833251] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[   36.833616] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   36.834546] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   36.834549] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[   36.834551] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[   36.834554] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 f4 23 ff f0 00 00 01 00
[   36.834557] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 32767999872 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   36.835039] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   36.835041] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[   36.835043] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[   36.835044] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 f4 23 ff f0 00 00 01 00
[   36.835046] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 32767999872 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   36.835049] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 4095999984, async page read
[   36.934613] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   36.934617] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[   36.934620] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[   36.934622] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 f4 23 ff e0 00 00 01 00
[   36.934626] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 32767999744 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   36.936631] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   36.936634] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[   36.936636] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[   36.936638] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 f4 23 ff e0 00 00 01 00
[   36.936641] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 32767999744 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   36.936645] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 4095995872, async page read
```

And lsusb:
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 048d:1234 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. Mass storage

Comment: So you have one big 16TB partition?  Maybe try two 8GB or four 4GB partitions, or switch to ntfs to see if that works.

Comment: Yup, brand new drive. Checking about partition/drive limits before I try that, as the whole drive seems unrecognised - I am hoping that's the right answer! NTFS I'm less keen on.

Comment: 16TB SSDs aren't "cheap". This is a common scam. The capacity is faked and when you try to use parts of the drive that aren't actually real, it will crash and suffer an early death. You get what you pay for.

Comment: If it appears in `lsusb` you can google the vendor & device id (in the form `ID abc0:0123`) and look online to see if others have run into the same problem. EDIT: Nmath makes a good point. It's a common scam to take a 8GB thumb drive and alter its firmware to make it report 16TB; but it just wraps to 0 when you write past 8GB; corrupting everything.

Comment: "*a litany of errors*" is vague. Copy those errors and paste them into your Question above.

Comment: When I get back home... you can have a page of details :) The question though, is asking about max limits (which is looking like a no) - I know I'll need to do the full monty for a fix!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not going to be 16TB, but hoping to get >4. Obviously expectations weren't high at the outset, it's chinese. I would like it to work a bit!

Comment: About the device: Vendor: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. Product: Chipsbank CBM2199 Flash Drive A quick search shows all their devices are basically crap.

Comment: The country of origin of the product is not really relevant. What's relevant is if you have a fake/scam product. 4TB SSDs aren't "cheap" either. Depending on your definition of "cheap", neither is a 1TB SSD. It probably contains 64 GB of solid state memory or less. Just enough for it to be barely functional.  And because they've fudged the firmware, you won't even be able to use that space reliably either. It's not like buying a carton of eggs where a few are broken. It's more like buying a carton of eggs that contains rocks instead of eggs.

Comment: Because of the way SSDs work, you can't use *any* of the space reliably, even with tricks to make a partition the size of the actual available space. This is because the firmware in the SSD can use any available space for wear-leveling, including space that doesn't exist. The drive is basically useless.

Comment: I think the comments have answered the question - so, I'll sum it as an Answer to quit it going to bounties & stuff....

Comment: I have bought on AliExpress a 16Tb disk a half year ago, I am now at 1,3Tb of usage with a lot of photo's of my dogs (Old German Shepperds Pedigree) in global. I paid for that device nearly 50€, shipping included. Now I see ePCM-system disks of 60Tb for about 40€. Bottom line: it works perfect !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, we have a lot of comments to the effect of, wasted £20 on junk.

The firmware is wrong, the thing will overwrite data randomly, I can't just set a smaller partition (I did try - now Windows doesn't recognise it either) as it can stray outside to balance wear & will use imaginary memory - WOM, I suppose - write only memory.

Caveat Emptor - but it's been an interesting delve. Hopefully this will save others £20. Heading off to leave feedback. Thank you for your thoughts.